# How to import python modules and use python scripts in SwiftUI with PythonKit?

Tags: javascript, python, ios, swift, iphone

```
**the SwiftUI file** 
import SwiftUI
import PythonKit
let main = Python.import("main.py") 
Button(action:{
        main.func($symptoms as! PythonConvertible)
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "arrowtriangle.forward")
            .font(.largeTitle)

            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .position(x:200, y:-200)
    }


**main.py**
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict


def func():
    try:
       from googlesearch import search
    except ImportError:
       print("No module named 'google' found, please install it")
  
...
```

Hi I'm relatively new to Swift and iOS app development and I've been trying to write an iOS app which uses a Python script to search google for a result, I've already installed the PythonKit in Xcode but I still can't use the function I defined in main.py, despite referencing it in the SwiftUI file. Every time the button is pressed, the xCode emulator just crashes and macOS returns a lengthy error message. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Incident Identifier: 71DDFD98-CB4A-418D-A935-4DA1B016CE80
CrashReporter Key:   6A294188-EAD4-9965-B4B8-AB5318EFF639
Thread 0 Crashed::  
0   libswiftCore.dylib                    0x18e02190c _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 1472
1   libswiftCore.dylib                    0x18e02190c _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 1472
2   SymptoCheck                           0x1044a5034 closure #1 in variable initialization expression of static PythonLibrary.pythonLibraryHandle + 496
3   SymptoCheck                           0x1044a4e34 one-time initialization